# IIS Rewrite Not Working

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, url-rewriting

I'm trying to get URL rewriting working but having problems. I have several rules set up with BlogEngine.NET and I want to redirect several pages to a "Coming Soon" page. Despite being able to access a valid page at mydomain.com/page/coming-soon.aspx by typing it directly, if I try to access it via mydomain.com/category.aspx, the rule below does not work - I just get a 404 that '/page/coming-soon.aspx' does not exist.

```
  <rule name="Coming Soon4" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^category.aspx/?$" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="page/Coming-Soon.aspx" />
  </rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't you mean to have `type="Redirect"` instead of `Rewrite`?

Comment: Ideally I was looking to rewrite, but the same problem happens if I try to redirect instead.